# How to remove items from debug window in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, ide

I have debugged my application a few times.

Every time I have stopped I pressed the double "X" sign to clean not running dumps.

However there are 5 items in debug window that just don't remove themselves even after pressing double X sign.

How can I clean them from that window?

Comment: Restart eclipse.  There is an entry in the File menu.

Comment: Have you tried terminate and remove option which you can see by right click on particular process